# " is being changed to \ when constructing json string in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I am creating a JSON formatted string. The output is correct except that all qoutes has been replaced with the \ char instead of "

```
{
    \$schema\: \https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#\,
    \contentVersion\: \1.0.0.0\,
    \parameters\: {
\type\:  \web\,
\name\:  \Cluster\,
\hockeyAppToken\:  \\,
\hockeyAppId\:  \\,
\regionId\:  \southcentralus\,
\requestSource\:  \IbizaAIExtension\
}
}
```

The code that generates the Json

```
$fullDoc = '
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": ' + $armsettings + '}'

$json = $fullDoc |  ConvertTo-Json -depth 100
$json = $json.Replace("\r","")
$json = $json.Replace("\n",([Environment]::NewLine))
$json = $json.Replace("@{","{")
$json = $json.Trim()
$json = $json.Replace($json.Substring(0,1),"")         

Write-Host $json
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

This is the correct formatted document

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "type": {
        "value": "web"
    },
    "name": {
        "value": "Cluster"
    },
    "hockeyAppToken": {
        "value": ""
    },
    "hockeyAppId": {
        "value": ""
    },
    "regionId": {
        "value": "southcentralus"
    },
    "requestSource": {
        "value": "IbizaAIExtension"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why not `$fullDoc | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json` ??

Comment: what the hell does that achieve? @Avshalom

Comment: @Avshalom . Thank you! That works like a charm :)

Comment: sure, you welcome

Comment: btw, that is not the proper parameters file format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fullDoc | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: so what the hell does this do? how can it build the json?

Comment: his problem was, that he try to manipulate the json with string replace tools etc. when he can get to the right results with built-in convertFrom-Json

Comment: convertfrom-json doesn't build json, it creates an object

Comment: he did not try to built anything, just to get to right look json string results.

Comment: this makes as much sense as his question